# NAET - is it a hoax or does it have any merit?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, homeopathy, allergies

[Nambudripad's Allergy Elimination Techniques](http://www.naet.com/) seems to claim to be able to heal almost anything.

It primarily focuses on allergies as the core of all issues. It seems to talk of meridians in human body that get blocked and can be the cause of almost all illness.

From their website:

> For our purposes, an allergy is defined in terms of what a substance does to the energy flow in the body. When contact is made with an allergen, it causes blockages in the energy pathways called meridians, or we can say, it disrupts the normal flow of energy through the body's electrical circuits. This energy blockage causes interference in communication between the brain and body via the nervous system. This blocked energy flow is the first step in a chain of events that can develop into an allergic response.

I have [watched proponents](http://www.naet.com/Patients/media.aspx) take a substance they are supposedly allergic to and place it in a glass, hold it up in one hand, and have another person grab their other hand as the surrogate, then the "doctor" pushes on that persons back in just the right spots on the surrogate's back in order to open the channels.
This seems as bad as voodoo to me but there are some die hard people who believe in it.

Does anyone have any proof one way or the other?

Comment: anything claiming XXX is "at the core of all issues" is a fraud. So does anything talking about "meridians in the body" because those don't exist.

Comment: I added links to the videos and added relevant quotes from the websites. Hope that helps.

Comment: In any case, you can immediately tell it is a fraud by the fact that (and I quote from [their website](http://www.naet.com/Patients/whatsnaet.aspx)) *NAET does NOT claim to cure allergies or food, chemical and environmental sensitivities.*. So... it is an allergy **elimination** technique that does not cure allergies... interesting indeed!

Comment: in the website store in red letters: "Devices sold through this website have not been tested or proven to diagnose or treat any medical conditions"